# SQL query to filter the records based on a value across columns

Tags: sql, oracle

My Scenario is to filter out the records which are having the value "RED" in any of the column

For eg: table name : Colors

```
ID   Col1     Col2   Col3
1    BLUE     RED      YELLOW
2    RED      GREEN    PINK
3    YELLOW    BLACK    BLUE
4    WHITE     GREY      RED
```

I have to retrieve the records 1,2,4 because they have RED in at least one of its column. I tried below query for the 3-column table

```
Select * from Colors
where Col1= 'RED' or Col2= 'RED' or Col3 ='RED'
```

But what if i have 100+ columns in the table Colors. Is there any other way to filter for this condition?

Comment: Maybe ...WHERE 'red' IN (col1,col2,col3,...,col100)?

Comment: you have a design issue, try to get your data into third normal form, and these issues will resolve themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you want to search through all columns with type VARCHAR2 you can find all ids of rows that contain 'Red' in a 'table' named 'Colors' like this:

```
DECLARE
    type found_array_t is varray(10000) of varchar2(100);
    found_array  found_array_t;
-- Type the owner of the tables you are looking at
  v_owner VARCHAR2(255) :='owner';

-- Type the data type you are look at (in CAPITAL)
-- VARCHAR2, NUMBER, etc.
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(255) :='VARCHAR2';

-- Type the string you are looking at
  v_search_string VARCHAR2(4000) :='RED';

BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols where owner=v_owner and (data_type = v_data_type or column_name='ID') and table_name = 'Colors') 
  LOOP
    IF t.column_name != 'ID' THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'SELECT ID FROM '||t.table_name||' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'
        BULK collect INTO found_array
        USING v_search_string;
        FOR j IN 1..found_array.count
        LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name ||' '||found_array(j) );
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you want to query a table with +100 column. just try this:

```
CL SCR

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    where_str   VARCHAR2(3000);
    str         VARCHAR2(3000);
    col_list    VARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
    where_str := 'SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,'' = ''''RED'''' OR '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) || '' = ''''RED'''' '' FROM all_tab_cols
                  WHERE OWNER=''VARSA'' AND table_name=''COLOR'' AND  data_type=''VARCHAR2''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE where_str INTO col_list;
    str := 'SELECT * FROM COLOR WHERE ' || col_list;
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
END;
```

This block gives you a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM COLOR WHERE COL1 = 'RED' OR COL2 = 'RED' OR COL3 = 'RED';
```

Then you can run the query and see the result.